# How to define the default import for a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging, pythonpath

I have a project with the following structure:

```
run.py
|--- /models
|------- /adaboost
|------------ Adaboost.py
|------------ EstimatorFactory.py (used in Adaboost.py)
|------- /me
|------------ Me.py
```

If current python versions don't require an `__init__.py` file, is there a way to define what is exported by a module (i.e. i would like `/adaboost` module to export `AdaboostClassifier` by default, so i don't have to call `adaboost.Adaboost.AdaboostClassifier` everytime)?

Comment: Possible issue in `Adaboost.py`, are you trying to import from `EstimatorFactory`? Can you share the contents of `Adaboost.py`

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, i just found out it was an issue. However, the second question remains: is there a way to define the default export of a module? (i will edit the question)

Comment: @john-hen could you please show, for this case, how can i set `__init__.py` properly? I tried many times, but i am clearly doing something wrong.